# Twig Cycle - how to show different html based on cycle

Tags: templating, php

Here is my code so far:

```
{% for event in post.get_field('timeline_event') %}
{% set items = [odd, even]%}
{{ cycle (items, loop.index0) }}

{% if cycle == odd %}
<div></div>
{% endif %}

{% if cycle == even %}
<div></div>
{% endif %}
```

This is working for the most part, the issue is the code I have is being duplicated twice.

Here is an image: [image: twig-cycle issue]

I know how to do this in jekyll liquid using capture, hit a roadblock using twig for php

Answer (score 4):

I tried this and this worked out also:

```
{% if loop.index is even %}
<div></div>
{% endif %}

{% if loop.index is odd %}
<div></div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [docs](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html):

```
{% for event in events %}
    {{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) }}
{% endfor %}
```

or (achieves the same thing):

```
{% for event in events %}
    {% set oddOrEven = cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) %}
    {{ oddOrEven }}
{% endfor %}
```

So, for different HTML:

```
{% for event in events %}
    {% set oddOrEven = cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) %}
    {% if oddOrEven == 'odd' %}
        <div class="Odd">Odd</div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="Even">Even</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No worries. Does it answer your question?